# How to implement data residency in my WordPress site

Tags: plugins, multisite, database, users, multi-language

I am developing a WordPress multi-site with woo-commerce and subscription plugin. This site will be used in several country like Bangladesh, Australia, United States and Canada.

But I want user’s data will be store accordingly to their region. Suppose Australian user’s data will be store in Australian data center and Canadian user’s data will be store in Canadian data center.

That means I want to implement the Data Residency feature in this system. But I don’t know how to implement or develop this feature with WordPress.

Someone can ask me why I want to implement this feature with WordPress. Yes, it is a valid ask but this is my client requirement and he must want this Data Residency feature with WordPress.

Can anybody help me to make the decision that is it possible or not with this stack. If possible, then please help me to resolve this issue and give me the solution of below question.

- How to configure Data Residency with WordPress?
- How to manage the database structure to resolve this issue?
- If any user wants to change him/her residence, such as from US to
  Canada then how to transfer/move their user information
  programmatically.

Comment: You can't really, I don't think - WordPress expects everything to be in one database. Is it just database data or do you have per-user uploaded files too? The simplest WordPress-based solution is to run separate installations in each region, but you could possibly override enough of WPDB so that it can switch between different databases as necessary - but that would be a lot of work.

Comment: You have to use separate installations. Multisite works on one single database.